# How to detect when route changed and new view replaced in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-routing

I am looking to detect when route changed and new view(html) replaced.

Tried below code but don't know how to proceed further.

```
this._routerSub = this.router.events
  .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  //.do(event => console.log(event)) // 
  .subscribe((value) => { });
```

Also tried below code but getting error

> Argument of type Event is not assignable to parameter of type
>   '(value:Event)=>void'.

```
   import { Router, NavigationEnd, Event  } from '@angular/router';

   this._routerSub = this.router.events  
      .subscribe(event : Event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        console.log(event.url);
      }
    });
```

Vega below are my app.component.ts and app.component.ts code. Isn't it suppose to call onActivate on activate. As router outlet will emit an activate event any time a new component is being instantiated.

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)" ></router-outlet>
```

app.component.ts

```
   onActivate(e) {
        debugger;
        console.log(1);
      }
```

Comment: Could you give more context?

Comment: I want to know when/how to call onActivate ?

Comment: I meant some relevent code

Comment: sry @Vega, I am not getting what more code is required, I have updated my question and provide my app.component.ts and app.component.ts. Pl let me know what else code is required?

Comment: Did you have declare routes in app.module ?

Comment: Yea, that was missing. Its working now, but its working same as "event instanceof NavigationEnd" not after view render..

Comment: You can keep in a property the last component name and on each activate check if the component changed

Comment: Have you solved this one?

Comment: not yet @Vega..

Comment: Any possibility to make a demo or add some more code to illustrate the issu? Because, (activate) is called each time the route is activated so the component is rendered. There is something else in your code blocking, nence the need to see the rest, or some other part of your code

Comment: (activate) is called before the complete page render, i am looking for alternate of AfterViewInit, can't use AfterViewInit as its being called only once..

Comment: actually m also looking in gaurds, and trying emitters and HttpInterceptor.. seems it will work for me.. will let u know..

Answer (score 8):

How about using router-outlet exposed `activate` event:

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>

onActivate(e) {
  console.log(e.constructor.name);
  //etc... you can access to a lot of other information
}
```

Comment: its not calling onActivate function?